# How to extract text from insight object in UFT

Tags: automated-testing

suppose if we have insight object like below:

**Window("Microsoft Word").InsightObject("InsightObject_Example").Click**

how to extract text from "InsightObject_Example"??

please help me

Comment: if that insight object is changing dyanamically how to get the text from it?

Answer (score 2):

GetVisibleText should give you the text from the insight object

```
Window("Microsoft Word").InsightObject("InsightObject_Example").GetVisibleText
```